# Ampere's Law with dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-flux, dielectric, coaxial

I am asked to calculate the magnetic-field-strength and magnetic-flux-density for different regions inside a coaxial-cable. I found Ampere's Law for that, but it uses \$\mu_0\$ , and the coaxial-cable in question has an isolation-region between its inner and outer conductor, for which \$\mu_r = 3\$. Is it valid to just use \$ \oint{\pmb{B} \cdot d\pmb{l} = \mu_0\mu_r \, I_{\text{encl}} } \$? Or do I have to apply a completely different formula in such case?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean \$\epsilon_r\$ is 3? It's almost unheard of to have a coax dielectric that has a magnetic permeability greater than that of free-space.

Comment: Yes, that's what the exercise states. I would not be surprised if it was sth. just to make the exercise harder, without being realistic.

Comment: Then use \$\mu_0\mu_r\$. Are you aware that the magnetic field between the shield and inner is due only to the inner wire current (assuming inner wire current and outer wire current are the same but opposite polarity)? For the same reason, there is no external field beyond the shield.

Comment: Thanks - I am semi-aware (I realize that ampere's law has this implication, but the underlying physics that make it be that way are not totally clear to me).
Also I found [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480976/permeability-constant-in-amp%C3%A8res-circuital-law-must-be-vacuum-permeability-mu](Thread from physics-SE) which is very related.